# Changing simulated matrics screws up layouts in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I built a nice fancy layout for iPhone and then decided I should try make it look a little better on the iPad. So, I changed some of the constraints (as I should have) and changed the Simulated Matrics to "iPad Full Screen". Things seemed OK until this point. However, when I changed back to iPhone, some controls were lost off screen, in the wrong place and some seem to have totally vanished. It's also not doing things like transforming a progress bar I use, but it used to.

One note: I started out with support for only iPhone. I went and changed that setting in my projects options and it said to me it was going to create a "Main-iPad"... I cant find this file anywhere.

- 1/ How do I recover the controls which have gone far outside the view
  controller?
- 2/ Is there something I'm missing here? Each time I change the
  simulated matrics, it screws up the other devices layout.
- 3/ Has the new "Main-iPad" storyboard file been hidden somewhere? Or
  integrated into the "Main" file I currently have?

PS> 1st app and rather new to Xcode...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To recover the controls you can go to the "document outline" in the project interface and find your object there. Then go to the size inspector an set the X and Y to 0, so the control will be reset to the top left corner.